# New ceiling fan, now wall switches are reversed

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

I installed a new ceiling fan yesterday. I hooked up white to white, black to black and red (from ceiling) to blue (from ceiling fan)

Now the switches on the wall are reversed. The light switch now turns on the fan and the fan switch turns on the light.

There is also a second wall switch that controlled the lights but now controls the fan.

Fan speed is controlled from the fan pull chain.

The original wall switch that controlled the lights has a black, red and white wire connected to it. The fan switch has a black and red wire connected to it.

The original fan had a black, white and blue wire but I didn't pay attention to what was connected to what from the ceiling.

What do I need to change to get the light switch to control the lights and the fan switch to control the fan?

I think I just need to hook the blue ceiling fan wire to the black ceiling wire and the black ceiling fan wire to the red ceiling wire.  But I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix is probably in the ceiling, as you describe. Making the fix in the switch box could lead to problems with the three-way switches if you're not clear on how that's set up.

There are no rules about which hot powers which device. Use them either way. Just be sure the neutrals stay where they belong.

Comment: Yes! stay away from the switch box.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments, especially on resolved questions.